# What is a "cell class" in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Or, more specific: what is the difference between `ConvLSTM2D` and `ConvLSTM2DCell`?

What is the difference between [`SimpleRNN` and `SimpleRNNCell`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#simplernncell)?

Same question for [GRU and GRUCell](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#grucell)

Keras manuals are not very verbose here.

I can see from RTFS (reading those *fine* sources) that these classes are descendants of different base classes. Those, with names, ending with `Cell`, are subclasses of `Layer`.

In my task I need to classify video sequences. That is, my classifier's input is a sequence of video frames, and the output is a single label (one-hot encoded vector).

What class should I use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference is the same for every cell layer combo:

- **Cell**: The cell is the actual computation component, they take a single input, a past state and produce an output, new states. These actually perform the **step** function which contain the computation of a GRU cell for example.
- **RNN Layer**: These layers wrap the corresponding cells to apply the **same** cell to *multiple timesteps*. So the cell is iterated over the input sequence and collect the output(s) based on extra options such as `return_sequences`.

Comment: In my task, I need to classify video sequences into one of several categories. That is, my input is a sequence of video frames, and output is a label, that can be, for example, a one-hot vector (I'm in process of setting my task). I should use subclasses of `Layer`, right?

Comment: Yes, you almost never use cells directly if you already have sequences. Because even though cells are subclasses of Layer they have a slightly different call signature to take into account states etc.

Comment: Then, it looks like, not yes, but no. I should use `ConvLSTM2D`, not `ConvLSTM2DCell`.

Comment: Yes, use the wrapping layers that actually iterate over the timesteps for you.