# NN in Keras - expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10980, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, word-embedding

I want to train a **Neutral Network** for **Multi-Classification Sentiment Analysis** using **word embedding** for tweets.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, GRU
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding


from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

## Import the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv('Tweets.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

## clean the tweets

```
def remove_mentions(input_text):
    return re.sub(r'@\w+', '', input_text)

def remove_stopwords(input_text):
    stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english')
    whitelist = ["n't", "not", "no"]
    words = input_text.split() 
    clean_words = [word for word in words if (word not in stopwords_list or word in whitelist) and len(word) > 1] 
    return " ".join(clean_words) 

df.text = df.text.apply(remove_stopwords).apply(remove_mentions)
df.text = [tweet for tweet in df.text if type(tweet) is str]

X = df['text']
y = df['airline_sentiment']
```

## Split my data into train and test

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.25, random_state=37)
```

## One-Hot Encode the field "Sentiment"

Originally the labels are of type string: 'neutral', 'positive', 'negative'. So I first transform them to integer and then apply one-hot encoding:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
y_train_num = le.fit_transform(y_train.values)
y_test_num = le.fit_transform(y_test.values)

nb_classes = 3
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train_num, nb_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test_num, nb_classes)
```

## Prepare for Word Embedding

```
tokenizer_obj = Tokenizer()
tokenizer_obj.fit_on_texts(X)
max_length = max([len(tweet.split()) for tweet in X])
print("max_length=%s" % (max_length))

vocab_size = len(tokenizer_obj.word_index) + 1 
print("vocab_size=%s" % (vocab_size))

X_train_tokenized = tokenizer_obj.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test_tokenized = tokenizer_obj.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

X_train_pad = pad_sequences(X_train_tokenized, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
X_test_pad = pad_sequences(X_test_tokenized, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
```

## Define and Apply my NN Model

```
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
    
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train_pad, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_test_pad, y_test), verbose=2)
```

**The reason I chose my last layer to have 3 output units is because it's a multi-classification task and I have 3 classes.**

Here is the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 23, 100)           1488200   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 23, 8)             808       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 23, 3)             27        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,489,035
Trainable params: 1,489,035
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When the code gets to `model.fit()`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10980, 3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the output of the `model.summary()`, the model output shape is `(None, 23, 3)` whereas you want it to be `(None, 3)`. That happens because [the Dense layer is applied on the last axis of its input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607) and does not flatten its input automatically (if it has more than 2 dimensions). Therefore, one way to resolve this is to use a `Flatten` layer right after the `Embedding` layer:

```
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
```

This way the output of the `Embedding` layer would be flattened and the following Dense layers would have 2D output.

As a bonus(!), you might be a able to get a better accuracy if you use a `LSTM` layer right after the `Embedding` layer:

```
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

However, this is not guaranteed. You must experiment and tune your model properly.

Comment: With `LSTM` I got a maximum value of accuracy : `val_acc = 0.74` even while manipulating its parameter. With `Flatten()` I got a maximum value of `val_acc=0.76` which is better than `LSTM` but not by much. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve my model further? Thank you.

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Well, there are lots of ways to improve the model. Is it overfitting, i.e. the training accuracy is much better than validation accuracy? If that's the case, have you tried using regularization, such as adding a `Dropout` layer? Further, have you tried increasing the embedding dimension or tune the number of units in each layer? Also, you can try stacking multiple `LSTM` layers on top of each other (see the point #2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255374/2099607)) to increase the model capacity if it is underfitting (i.e. the training accuracy is low).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answer I too would suggest using an LSTM layer. try this once.

```
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train_pad, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_test_pad, y_test), verbose=2)
```

and for hidden layers we need not specify input_shpae or input_dim in a [Keras.Sequential()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), yes training will be drastically slow for LSTM compared to plain Dense layer but it is worth the time.